# OpenAPI 3 - Webflux - Path parameter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am working on OpenAPI3 based integration for my Spring Boot app.

https://springdoc.org/#spring-webfluxwebmvc-fn-with-functional-endpoints

For single routing function:

```
@Bean
@RouterOperation(operation = @Operation(operationId = "findEmployeeById", summary = "Find purchase order by ID", tags = { "MyEmployee" },
      parameters = { @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = "id", description = "Employee Id") },
      responses = { @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Employee.class))),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid Employee ID supplied"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Employee not found") }))
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getEmployeeByIdRoute() {
   return route(GET("/employees/{id}"),
         req -> ok().body(
               employeeRepository().findEmployeeById(req.pathVariable("id")), Employee.class));
}
```

For multiple functions,

```
@RouterOperations({ @RouterOperation(path = "/getAllPersons", beanClass = PersonService.class, beanMethod = "getAll"),
      @RouterOperation(path = "/getPerson/{id}", beanClass = PersonService.class, beanMethod = "getById"),
      @RouterOperation(path = "/createPerson", beanClass = PersonService.class, beanMethod = "save"),
      @RouterOperation(path = "/deletePerson/{id}", beanClass = PersonService.class, beanMethod = "delete") })
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> personRoute(PersonHandler handler) {
   return RouterFunctions
         .route(GET("/getAllPersons").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::findAll)
         .andRoute(GET("/getPerson/{id}").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)), handler::findById)
         .andRoute(POST("/createPerson").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::save)
         .andRoute(DELETE("/deletePerson/{id}").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::delete);
}
```

We parameters option for the single function.

`parameters = { @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = "id", description = "Employee Id")`

But, I am not sure how this can be achieved with the multiple functions. There is no parameters option. It has params but it doesn't take the type.